# What are ways to reduce memory usage by a NodeJS program that is using worker threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heap-memory, worker-thread

I have a program that processes a file of 5million address lines. It reads them in one at a time, places those in chunks, extracts some data and then some more data, and then returns the updated chunk to a file writer to print out one line at a time to a different file. I use read streams, file streams, and I just started experimenting with worker threads for one of the data extractions. What are reasons it could be reaching a Javasccript heap out of memory issue, and what are possible ways to improve it?

I'm not linking all the code for reasons of its way too big a program, but here's how I'm managing the worker threads

Function that gets called on each chunk to extract extra data (inData contains the array of the chunk, addProper is reference data that gets compared to and is a key:value object, DataOut is the function that writes the chunk to file; it is not async)

```
//Check if other details of the address are correct by the post code
DataValid: async function DataValid(inData, final) {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //Check if city is correct
        let worker = new Worker('./cityprocess.js', {workerData: [inData, addProper]});
        worker.on('message', (message) => resolve(message));
        worker.on('error', reject);

        //Pass updated list with validated cities to DataOut
    });

    promise.then((val) => {
        this.DataOut(val, final);
    });
},
```

This is how I start up the script that is the worker thread (the cityprocess.js script)

```
if (workerData != null) {
    ChunkPull(workerData[0]);
}
```

This is the function that is called at the end of the chunk processing, when its time to return the updated chunk to the main script (addChunk is that updated chunk)

```
function ReturnParentMessage(code) {
    parentPort.postMessage(addChunk);
    worker.terminate();
}
```

The code also seems to buffer the threads, as it'll process a few chunks with the threads and then write out all the outputs of about 5 threads at once before processing more. I was planning to fix this by having the writer get called by the worker threads directly

Comment: You never unregister the event listeners you register in your promise constructor, that will definitely use a lot of memory. Your `DataValid()` function also doesn't follow the completion of `promise`, so that's a logic error in your code.

Comment: How do I unregister those? Also how do you mean it doesn't follow the completion?

Comment: What are the threads for if you're asking to do something one line at a time?

Comment: I'm planning to use multiple threads but I was running it one line at a time until I figured out how worker threads properly work